# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler": In Gemfile: rails (= 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on bundler (~> 1.0.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I just bought a new MBP and I'm trying to execute a ruby app. After I followed this tutorial [Install Ruby on Rails 5.0 · macOS Sierra](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html),
I'm still having this issue:

```
MBP:test_app $ gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-5.0.1
Parsing documentation for rails-5.0.1
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
MBP:test_app $ rails new .
Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.0.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Try running `bundle install`.
```

Then, I tried:

```
$ bundle install
```

And I got the following error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.13.7)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Could not find gem 'bundler (~> 1.0.0)', which is required by gem 'rails (=
3.0.0)', in any of the sources.
```

I guess I've already tried everything; installed bundler 1.0.0, reinstalled, deleted gems, removed ruby, rails, rvm, and installed everything again.

Please, any advice?

Comment: you explicitly declared `bundler 1.0.0` in your gemfile and it still didn't work? I would go through your other gems then and see if any of them depend on newer versions of bundler because something is moving your Bundler version to 1.13.7

Comment: Also why are you installing rails 5.0.1, but then requiring rails 3.0.0 in your gemfile? Which version of rails do you want your project to work with?

Comment: Are you working within a Gemset by any chance? I'd suggest first installing bundler `gem install bundler` and then `gem install rails`

Comment: @BigRon I didn't require 3.0.0. I just wanted to run my first app. Do I have to change anything?

Comment: @DarioBarrionuevo I did, but I still have the problem

Comment: I have these in my `gem list`: `bundler (1.13.7, 1.0.22, 1.0.0)` and `rails (5.0.1, 3.0.0)` but it still doesn't work

Comment: Something funny is going on with your versions of `bundler` and `rails`. RVM misconfiguration is the most probable cause. For now, do not install rails `3.0.0`, or anything other than bundler `1.13.7` (uninstall them.). Delete any references to these versions. When you're done, run `rails -v` (which should return `5.0.1`), then `rails new .`. Double check that the `Gemfile` contains nothing weird.

Comment: @TomLord I did what you said. Uninstalled rails 3.0.0 and other than bundler 1.13.7. However, when I typed `rails -v` I have `Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.0.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Try running `bundle install`.` Then, I've typed `bundle install` and got the same error: `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile: rails (= 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0)
  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.13.7)`

Comment: Can you list your whole Gemfile in the question?

Comment: @BigRon Sure! [link] (https://github.com/gustavoacardoso/ruby/issues/1)

Comment: That looks like your `$ gem list` not your `Gemfile` from your project. Bundler thinks something in your `Gemfile` is requiring `rails 3.0.0`

Comment: @BigRon Sorry, my bad. Here it is: [link] (https://github.com/gustavoacardoso/ruby/issues/1)

Comment: So change that 2nd line from `gem 'rails', '3.0.0'` to `gem 'rails', '5.0.1'`. Then run `bundle install`

Comment: @BigRon I did! Now, I got another error:  [link] <https://github.com/gustavoacardoso/ruby/issues/1)

Comment: open up `config/environments/development.rb` find `config.eager_load` (if it's not there, add it). Make it `config.eager_load = false`

Comment: File created but error keeps occurring

Comment: what do you mean file created? You didn't have `development.rb`?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I did have the file. I didn't have the line `config.eager_load`

Comment: $ rails server
/Users/gustavocardoso/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/Users/gustavocardoso/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myapp/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

Comment: I'd be more concerned with this line in your stacktrace: `/Users/gustavocardoso/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@myapp/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/railtie.rb:27:in block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>': undefined method debug_rjs=' for ActionView::Base:Class (NoMethodError)`. RJS is pre jquery and hasn't been used since Rails 3. You might be able to fix that by adding `prototype-rails` to your gemfile, but you are way out of date and will probably keep running into many more errors. You're just going to have to slowly plug through them.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

The problem was solved removing or commenting `config.action_view.debug_rjs = true` in `development.rb` file.

Thanks to everyone!